# ASP.NET count text in textbox when text gets added using a button

Tags: javascript, c#

I am currently creating a pin code sort of thing which uses buttons ranging from 1 - 9. When I click on the button a "1" for example gets added to the textbox, but my javascript code only counts the amount of characters added in the textbox when I type with my keyboard.

Currently I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function countChar(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= 4) {
      __doPostBack('<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>', '');
    }
  };
</script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword" class="AS_td_box"
  onkeypress="countChar(this)" AutoPostBack="true"
  style="text-align: center" Height="200px" Width="800px"
  OnTextChanged="txtPassword_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
```

This code is working, but only when I type with my keyboard and not when I press a button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add click event on textbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function txtPassword_ClientClicked() {
    // here add the code responsible for counting
  }
</script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword" class="AS_td_box"
  onkeypress="countChar(this)" AutoPostBack="true"
  style="text-align: center" Height="200px" Width="800px"
  OnTextChanged="txtPassword_TextChanged" onClick="txtPassword_ClientClicked()">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Hi @bush_dev, this did not work.. You've got any idea what is wrong?